# How can I change certain parts of a command in the system function in C++

Tags: c++, shell, variables

So I have this code. It's very simple

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string inputfile = "input.pdf";
string outputfile = "output.tiff";
cout << "paste path of pdf to convert" << endl;
cin >> inputfile;
cout << "type the path of the output file with the correct extension ie png jpeg or tif" << endl;
 cin >> outputfile;

system("gm.exe montage -tile 1x10000 -geometry 100% -density 200x200 input.pdf -quality 100 output.tif");

return 0;
}
```

So I want the user to change the two strings to whatever file path they need and put that into the command instead of `input` or `output` file. Is this even possible?

Comment: @Matt Coats answer is very good for your situation, however next time consider the use of conventional command line argument handling. Depending on the platform and audience this may be more standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string inputfile = "input.pdf";
string outputfile = "output.tiff";
cout << "paste path of pdf to convert" << endl;
getline(cin, inputfile);
cout << "type the path of the output file with the correct extension ie png jpeg or tif" << endl;
getline(cin, outputfile);
string command = "gm.exe montage -tile 1x10000 -geometry 100% -density 200x200 " + inputfile + " -quality 100 " + outputfile;

system(command.c_str());
```

Note that I now use `getline()` to gather input from the user -- I've just heard this is a better method, so I changed it here. Then I created a new string variable and concatenated the `inputfile` and `outputfile` strings to it to create the command string. Since the `system()` function requires a const char* as its parameter, I then use `c_str()` to convert the string to a const char*.

Please not that I have not tested this code, but the idea I've presented here should work.

Comment: One reason why `getline` is better: `>>` can't parse *c:\document and settings\batman\desktop\batmobile v4.2.7 design schematics.pdf* because of the spaces.

Comment: Although if you don't put double quotes around the two filenames in your command, GraphicsMagick won't process filenames with spaces in them!

Comment: thank you everyone the input was much appreciated  all i needed to now  was to unquote and put the variable